# Reading binary file with python without knowing structure

Tags: python, arrays, list, binary, decoding

I have a binary file containing the position of 8000 particles. 
I know that each particle value should look like "-24.6151..." (I don't know with which precision the values are given by my program. I guess it is double precision(?).

But when I try to read the file with this code:

```
In: with open('.//results0epsilon/energybinary/energy_00004.dat', 'br') as f:
    buffer = f.read()
    print ("Lenght of buffer is %d" % len(buffer))

    for i in buffer:
        print(int(i))
```

I get as output:

```
Lenght of buffer is 64000

10

168

179

43
...
```

I skip the whole list of values but as you can see those values are far away from what I expect. I think I have some kind of decoding error.

I would appreciate any kind of help :)

Comment: I can try `struct` library to unpack binary files - https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Comment: You cn use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module to unpack (or pack) binary data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are printing now are the `bytes` composing your floating point data. So it doesn't make sense as numerical values.

Of course, there's no 100% sure answer since we didn't see your data, but I'll try to guess:

You have 8000 values to read and the file size is 64000. So you probably have `double` IEEE values (8 bytes each). If it's *not* IEEE, then you're toast.

In that case you could try the following:

```
import struct
with open('.//results0epsilon/energybinary/energy_00004.dat', 'br') as f:
    buffer = f.read()
    print ("Length of buffer is %d" % len(buffer))

    data = struct.unpack("=8000d",buffer)
```

if the data is printed bogus, it's probably an endianness problem. So change the `=8000` by `<8000` or `>8000`.

for reference and packing/unpacking formats: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Comment: with print(data) I got the following output (-24.615130168305804, -24.61513016830572...) as expected. Now I can process it further. Thank you very much :)